# JQuery UI 1.8.10 Cannot read property '3' of undefined

Tags: php, jquery, jquery-ui, jquery-selectors

I use JQuery UI 1.8.10 and jquery latest.

My code is:

```
<script src="http://code.jquery.com/jquery-latest.js"></script>
<script src="http://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jqueryui/1.8.10/jquery-ui.js"></script>
<script type="text/javascript" src="/cms/ww.admin/login/login.js"></script>
</head>
<body>

<div id="header"></div>
<?php
    if(isset($_REQUEST['login_msg']))
    {
        require SCRIPTBASE.'cms/ww.incs/login-codes.php';
        $login_msg = $_REQUEST['login_msg'];
        if(isset($login_msg_codes[$login_msg]))
        {
            echo '<script>$(function(){$("<strong>'.htmlspecialchars($login_msg_codes[$login_msg]).'</strong>").dialog({modal:true});});</script>';
        }

?>
```

why does this give a cannot read property '3' of undefined error?

the file that gives the error is `jquery-ui.js on line 186`

okay now i changed it to:

```
</head>
<body>

<div id="header"></div>
<div id="login-msg"></div>
<?php
if(isset($_REQUEST['login_msg'])){
require SCRIPTBASE.'cms/ww.incs/login-codes.php';
$login_msg=$_REQUEST['login_msg'];
if(isset($login_msg_codes[$login_msg])){
   echo '<script>$(function(){
                    $("#login-msg").html("<strong>'.htmlspecialchars($login_msg_codes[$login_msg]).'</strong>").dialog({modal:true});});</script>';
}
}
 ?>
```

But still the same error

Comment: are you sure that you don't need / before `'cms/ww.incs/login-codes.php';

Comment: What line/file gives you that error??

Comment: no i dont need a / before cms because thas in de scriptbase.

Comment: and the file is jquery-ui.js on line 186

Comment: Can you post the code that is using jquery-ui?

Comment: echo '<script>$(function(){$("<strong>'.htmlspecialchars($login_msg_codes[$login_msg]).'</strong>").dialog({modal:true});});     </script>';

Comment: If you replace your PHP, with a straight up piece of javascript, does it work? I.E. replace all your php with: `$(function(){$("<strong>test string</strong>").dialog({modal:true});});​`

Comment: minimize your question to the bare minimum. [this fiddle](http://jsfiddle.net/mZPWS/) shows the same error! Just striped down to the minimum.

Answer (score 20, accepted):

It's a bug from your jQueryUI which use a :data selector (if you go up in the call stack you will see it) which is deprecated/not compatible with latest jQuery.
Try with this jQueryUI :

```
http://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jqueryui/1.8.22/jquery-ui.min.js
```

example here :

http://jsfiddle.net/techunter/RyUVq/

Comment: You can write $("<p>text</p>").dialog(), but it is indeed not advisable since you cannot take any actions on that dialog later on (no selector).

Comment: Thank you your my hero i as googling and trying to find a fix al morning thank you.

Answer (score 2):

You found a bug/incompatibility!!

this isn't working jquery (1.8.0): http://jsfiddle.net/mZPWS/

Older jquery version (1.7.2) is working: http://jsfiddle.net/mZPWS/1/

Answer (score 0):

It might not be the source of your problem, but maybe setting a div for your .dialog() widget can help you.

Your js line `$("<strong>'.htmlspecialchars($login_msg_codes[$login_msg]).'</strong>").dialog({modal:true}` seems to be using a simple message, which in most cases works.

Can you try changing using this line instead :

```
$(function()
{
    $("#header") // or any div you have
    .html("<strong>'.htmlspecialchars($login_msg_codes[$login_msg]).'</strong>")
    .dialog({modal:true});
});
```

also, make sure your "/cms/ww.admin/login/login.js" is not the source of the error, the js error console gets easily lost and can point you to jquery-ui.js while the error is somewhere else.

Comment: Remove the comment, .html needs to follow the selector if put on the same line. I added a line to my answer, what is in your login.js file?

Comment: i think you forgot a ) after function( that should be function() but no it is still not working

Comment: Updated, thank you! Have you tried removing the .dialog() part of the line? Do you still have errors without it? It would rule out this part and your error would definitely come from login.js

Answer (score 0):

I confirm the uncompatibility issue.
Tried with
jquery-1.8.0 and
jquery-ui-1.8.4