# Why can't I make jQuery UI 1.8.20 dialog work in JSFiddle?

Tags: javascript, jquery-ui, jquery-ui-dialog, jsfiddle

I'm trying to use [jQuery UI dialog](http://jqueryui.com/demos/dialog/) in JSFiddle, but opening the dialog fails consistently due to an error deep in the innards of jQuery UI: `Uncaught TypeError: Cannot read property '3' of undefined`.

I'm using jQuery UI 1.8.20, but I've found that if I switch to for example 1.7.1, it works fine. I've created a [fiddle](http://jsfiddle.net/aknuds1/L5BPz/5/) that should demonstrate the problem, just click the button saying 'Click me!' and you should see in your browser's console (e.g. in Chrome's developer tools) that a TypeError has been raised by jQuery UI.

What is going wrong here? Am I seeing some incompatibility between jQuery UI 1.8.20 and JSFiddle?

Comment: It has to do something with the actual ui source. :/ Something with 3...

Comment: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/11948082/jquery-ui-1-8-10-cannot-read-property-3-of-undefined

Comment: @YuriyRozhovetskiy Thanks, there is indeed a bug in jQuery UI 1.8.20, 1.8.22 solves it. Want to write that as an answer? Or should this question be closed as a duplicate??

Comment: @YuriyRozhovetskiy I voted to close it as a duplicate, apparently several votes are needed. I think my problem is better defined though than the "duplicate" question.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

There is an incompatibility between jQuery 1.8.0 and jQuery UI 1.8.20. Upgrading to jQuery UI 1.8.22 solves it.